# winforms1 C# using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

```
con = new SqlConnection(cs);
con.Open();
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
current = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
(CustomerId, Date, Name, Gender, Address, Phone, Email, MobileNo,Notes)
 VALUES  ('" + txtCustomerID.Text + "','" + current + "','" + 
 txtCustomerName.Text + "','"+Gender+"','"+txtAddress.Text+"','" + txtPhone.Text 
 + "','" + txtEmail.Text+"','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "','" +txtNotes.Text + "')", 
      con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

i am using this code in database my date has datetime datatype but when i am saving the data through form it is showing

> The conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been Terminated

What is problem? Why this error is showing ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i'm not understanding why this question hasbeen closed! though it is valid.

Comment: @user3327117: dont convert date into string, directly store `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: it is working on my friend pc but it is not working on my pc so what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

use `getdate()` or `SYSDATETIME()` function of sql if you want to store current date.

Try This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
(CustomerId, Date, Name, Gender, Address, Phone, Email, MobileNo,Notes)
 VALUES  ('" + txtCustomerID.Text + "',+ getdate() + ,'" + 
 txtCustomerName.Text + "','"+Gender+"','"+txtAddress.Text+"','" + txtPhone.Text 
 + "','" + txtEmail.Text+"','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "','" +txtNotes.Text + "')", 
      con);
```

**Suggestion :** your query is open to sql injection attacks so i'd suggest you to use Paramterised Queries to avoid them.

Comment: Or [SysDatetime()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) for more precision.

Comment: where to use SysDatetime()

Comment: check my answer above